# SSMA AccesToSQLAzure - exception in C# Access Application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, azure-sql-database, sql-server-migration-assi

I migrated my Access2007 (.accdb) to a SQL Azure Database with SQL Server Migration Assistant and it works great with some issues but thats not the point now.

Some time ago i wrote a C# Winforms application which connects to my Access Database and do some actions like updating and deleting datarows.

So I just migrated my Access Database to SQL Azure and I checked the checkbox to link the tables, in the description stood that my application can work with the Access Database without problems but the tables are physically stored in the SQL Azure Database, ok all right I thinked.

But now I get a exception while testing my C# Application, here it is:

ODBC-Connection to 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0'Databasename'.database.windows.net'failed.

I couldn't found something on the internet about this exception... I hope someone can help me with this, i'm really desperate on this...

Thanks and greets
Alexander

Comment: I would recommend you try installing and running the latest version of MS Access. I recall some issues early on with SQL Azure and Access which were addressed later.  Take a look at this thread; it contains nugets of information that may be interest to you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredata/thread/05dd7620-f209-43d2-8c41-63b251c62970

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re able to use SQL Azure in the migration assistant, I think you’ve probably configured SQL Azure firewall rules. Nevertheless, please check that again to make sure it is able to connect from your local machine to SQL Azure. Please also check if the connection string is correct. Moreover, I would like to suggest you to refer to an article that may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336243.aspx.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: The firewall rules are ok. I use the old ConnectionString to get the data from the Access Database, I think that is ok but i'm not sure. Here my Code with the ConnectionString I use to connect to my Access Database:        
private void openAccessDB()
{
    AccessCon = new OleDbConnection       ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.10.0;
 Data Source=C:\Users\ABO\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SQLAzure_test_winform\Resourcen\FSL.accdb");

    AccessCon.Open();
}

Maybe this causes the error? Or maybe I have to change Settings in Access? I have no idea...

Comment: Ah and thanks for your link. But I don't want to connect to Azure directly. I want to use my application like I used it before I load my Access Database to SQL Azure and linked the Tables.
Like I said, in the Migration Assistant is written that I can use my Application, which works with the Access Database, without problems after the migration...